# calling the Caller method in SignalR hub outside the hub context

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a question in my mind about the Caller method of SignalR. In the hub method we can call a client side function like this.

```
Clients.Caller.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
```

but when i use to call it from outside the hub context it is not found or not implemented?? like this..

```
 var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
 context.Clients.Caller.reportProgress(recordCount,totalCount);
```

Can someone enlighten me in this part or is there other way to implement it..
by now i use to implement this

```
 var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
 context.Clients.User(CurrentUser.Usernm).reportProgress(recordCount,totalCount);
```

but now we are not claim based authentication so it will be a problem if the same usernm are logged..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outside of the hub, there obviously is no caller because the server is the one who initiates.

If you are worried about unique user names, you'll need to [implement a custom `IUserIdProvider`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider), or you need to [manage connection ids per user](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) in some other way. Then you could call

```
context.Clients.Client(connectionId).reportProgress();
```

which would be unique.

Comment: mapping the user identity to the hub authentication is i guess the best way but we implemented custom Iprincipal. Gonna take a peek on the links..

Comment: solve my problem.. Yep IUserIdProvider map with my Iprincipal solves the connection mapping