# SignalR - accessing clients from other classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm new and experimenting SignalR, so go easy.

I know we can access clients of all sorts within the hub class itself by using

```
Clients.All
Clients.Others
Clients.Group
Clients.Caller
Clients.Client
```

However, whenever I try to access clients from other classes by the hub context

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
```

`hubContext` only gives me access to

```
hubContext.Clients.All
hubContext.Clients.Group
hubContext.Clients.Client
```

There are two questions I'd like some answers to.

1. How can I access Clients.Others/Caller from the `hubContext`?
2. How can I retrieve my mapped connectionlist in the hub from hubContext so that I can iterate through the list of connection ids to be passed over to Clients.Client() method?

Assuming my mapped user lists as below:

```
public static List<UserConnection> ActiveUsers = new List<UserConnection>();

//onConnected will add users of UserConnection class into ActiveUsers list

class UserConnection
{
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    public string ConnectionID { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: It's because inside your `NotificationHub`, Client is `IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>` type, but `GetHubContext<NotificationHub>()` method returns `IHubContext`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling the Caller method in SignalR hub outside the hub context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468294/calling-the-caller-method-in-signalr-hub-outside-the-hub-context)

Comment: A _caller_ (client) can obviously only exist in a `Hub` instance. Outside of this instance there can never be a caller. Hence no `Clients.Others` either, because this means, _all except the caller_

Comment: Noted on the answers to my first questions. How can I then retrieve the `ActiveUsers` list from `hubContext`?

Comment: Also, please help to look into this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385058/signalr-call-stacks-on-different-browser-for-notification

Comment: @NewbieCoder I doubt you can get the `ActiveUsers` from the hubcontext. You already solved the problem yourself: You made the list `public static`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514344/4634044